# Set textSize items of listeview

Tags: android, listview, text-size

1.I want to change the textSize of the items in my listView.
        I've a xml file with a button and a listView in a Fragment layout. 
        I can't change the size of the text's Items.
        I tried, in xml, android:textSize and i've searched here but the question is not   the same, because normally they haven't a button inside the activity (in my case, a fragment).

`My onResume with ArrayAdapter`

```
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        ListView listaDeEquipas=(ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listaEquipas);
        final ArrayAdapter<Equipa> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Equipa>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaEquipas);
        listaDeEquipas.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
        itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listaDeEquipas.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                listaEquipas.remove(position);
                itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }
        }); 
    }
```

`My xml code:`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addEquipa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:background="#FFCC0000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:text="Inserir Equipa"
        android:onClick="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listaEquipas"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true">   

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ListView adapter, place this line in your `getView()`:

```
TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
text.setTextSize(30);
```

You might need to implement a custom adapter for the ListView, like this:

```
package de.vogella.android.listactivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class myArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Equipa> {
private final Context context;
private final Equipa[] values;

public myArrayAdapter(Context context,Equipa[] values) {
super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
this.context = context;
this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View rowView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
TextView text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
text.setTextSize(30);
textView.setText(values[position]); // Set what you want the text to be here
return rowView;
 }
}
```